# ServiceStack ORMLite SqlList issue with DateTime

Tags: mysql, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am in the process of upgrading from v4.0.36 to v4.0.46 and I'm getting issues where the SQL that is generated through this API doesn't convert the DateTime values correctly:

```
public static List<T> SqlList<T> (this IDbConnection dbConn, string sql, object anonType = null);
```

The DateTime would be an attribute as part of object passed through to the method.

When on v4.0.36 the DateTime value would result in the string "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

However after upgrading to v4.0.46 the DateTime value is now "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss AM"

and because of this queries that rely on a date are now not returning any records because MySQL doesn't recognise this format.

Is there a config I'm missing? Or any pointers on what changes I need to make to get the same behaviour as 4.0.36?

Comment: please include the query that reproduces this issue as I'm not seeing this behavior when [querying DateTime in SqlList](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/3cc2a80f6423e5a3893e1fb716d38c075ac3b395).

Comment: I did some testing and it seems to only affect nullable DateTime objects. That test confirms it for normal DateTime, but not when the parameter is a nullable DateTime. I can fix this by creating a custom converter for "DateTime?" but it would be nice if it could just work out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should now be resolved [from this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/66189a2721aff60ec20181124feb5a3405443443), available from v4.0.47 that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet) which supports each of the call styles below:

```
class DateTest
{
    public DateTime Test { get; set; }
    public DateTime? TestNullable { get; set; }
}

using (var db = OpenDbConnection())
{
    db.DropAndCreateTable<DateTest>();

    var dateTime = new DateTime(2001, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
    db.Insert(new DateTest{ Test = dateTime, TestNullable = dateTime });

    var row = db.SqlList<DateTest>(
        "SELECT * FROM DateTest WHERE Test = @dateTime"), new { dateTime });

    row = db.SqlList<DateTest>(
        "SELECT * FROM DateTest WHERE TestNullable = @dateTime"), new { dateTime });

    DateTime? nullDate = dateTime;
    row = db.SqlList<DateTest>(
        "SELECT * FROM DateTest WHERE TestNullable = @nullDate"), new { nullDate });
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Do you know when will this version be available through nuget?

Comment: @vonec hoping for a release early next week.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with 4.0.52, this still breaks with a null value of DateTime?.  It's simple to get around;

```
 SqlServerDialect.Provider.RegisterConverter<DateTime?>(new SqlServerDateTimeConverter());
```